# c# Get remote socket from BeginConnect

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am having some trouble with some bi-directional socket code I wrote. I am connecting to a server like this:

```
_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("100.100.100.1"), 8677), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
_buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

Then in the callback I'm doing this:

```
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    _clientSocket.EndConnect(AR);

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CONNECT");
    _clientSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
}
```

I also need to receive data from the server, but I'm unclear on how to get the socket of the server during this process. I wrote some BeginReceive logic, but I'm consistently getting errors that I'm using the wrong socket.

It seems like somewhere in my above code I should be able to get the socket similar to how I'm doing it in my server's BeginAccept callback code:

```
_serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _serverSocket);
```

then in AcceptCallback:

```
Socket server = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
Socket client = server.EndAccept(AR);
```

It seems obvious to me that I'm just missing a step or concept to get me past this. I've done countless searches, but either I'm searching for the wrong thing or it's just not out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you actually don't need server side socket. You should use your client socket.
After connecting is completed, you can call `_clientSocket.BeginReceive()`. For example, in `ConnectCallback` method, as you did with `BeginSend`.
If you are getting exception with that, please add exact code you are using and exception you are getting.

Comment: You are 100% correct. The error I was seeing was actually from the server and not the client (with a copy/paste mishap that made it seem like the client).. I'm going to mark this as the answer because what you said was 100% correct.